# In Objective C, How can we add thumbnails on top of mapAnnotations?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, objective-c-2.0

I have set up all my annotations on my Map and I have pins set up all over it.

I want to open a little thumbnail that hold information about the pin when you touch that pin. (like title of the street ex.)

If there's a tutorial or a developer's page that has examples on that, it'd be great.

Sorry if I'm not clear as I should be.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the callouts... 
this is the [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009746-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)  by the apple... check out this too for the [callout reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html)